# Difference between pair of consts and const pair

Tags: c++, constants

In C++, what's the difference in behavior between `std::pair<const T, const U>` and `const std::pair<T, U>`?

Comment: They are different types, a function taking a reference to the first cannot take a reference to the other...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The core difference is that they are different unrelated types (with some implicit conversions among them).

```
void f(std::pair<std::string,std::string> const &);
std::string longstring();
int main() {
   std::pair<const std::string,const std::string> pc
        = std::make_pair(longstring(),longstring());
   f(pc);
   const std::pair<std::string,std::string> cp
        = std::make_pair(longstring(),longstring());
   f(cp); 
}
```

While there are implicit conversions that allow `f(pc)` to compile, that line involves a *conversion*, and the conversion involves making a *copy* of the `longstring()`s. On the other hand, the call `f(cp)` only binds a constant reference to the existing pair as the type matches, not requiring any copies.

The fact that the compiler let's you write similar code, does not mean that the code is compiled to do the same thing. This is particularly true for types with implicit conversions, as is the case of `std::pair`

This is a common pitfall when writing functors to operate on elements stored in maps, where a mismatch on the argument of the functor will cause unnecessary copying of the object data:

```
std::map<int,std::string> m = create_map();
std::for_each(m.begin(),m.end(),
              [](std::pair<int,std::string> const &r) { 
                    std::cout << r.second << " ";
              });
```

The lambda above does not have the correct type of argument (`std::pair<int,std::string` vs. `std::pair<const int,std::string>`) and that causes each call to copy both the index and the value (i.e. all strings will be copied, to an `std::pair<int,std::string>` and then a reference bound for the argument to the lambda). The simple recommendation in this case would be to use `std::map<int,std::string>::value_type const &` for the argument type.

Comment: Just spent the entire day groveling through stack traces, dissassemblies (from both MSVC++ and g++) and compiler debugging options to find what was killing performance, and it was exactly this -- implicit conversions (in both directions) between `pair<const int, set<int>>` and `pair<int, set<int>>`.  Finally added `const` to a few function signatures and almost tripled the speed!  :)

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm reading Stroustrup's "A Tour of C++" (3rd printing) and was confused about the pair<const string,int> on p113 morphing to const pair<string,int>& r in the lambda on p114, and I think this explains it.

Answer (score 0):

From the tests that I did, the behaviour is the same.

```
#include <utility>

int main() {
   std::pair<const int, const int> p = std::make_pair(2,3);
   p = std::make_pair(3, 4); // error
   p.first = 5; // also error

   const std::pair<int, int> p2 = std::make_pair(4,5);
   p2 = std::make_pair(4, 5); // error
   p2.first = 0; // error

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: In terms of mutability there are similar, but in terms of usage - where those types can be used (interface-wise), they are different.